# How can we add our custom css file in RTE in AEM 6?

Tags: aem, aem-6

How can we add our custom css file in RTE so that we can add custom css classes to selected content ?

Comment: Show your approach. What did you done so far?

Comment: I have created custom plugin for RTE and via that I am able to add my custom classes to selected text. Have no idea on how to apply CSS on these classes so that it will reflect on RTE itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize RTE plugins by following this blog here http://blogs.adobe.com/contentmanagement/2013/09/17/customized-multifield-richtext-editor-part-2/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.